# Android Studio 2.2 Losing Constraints?

Tags: android

So I have been trying to create a pretty basic calculator app.

I converted my RelativeLayout to a ConstraintLayout and started creating constraints.
[image]

After some time I noticed that while creating new constraints, the older ones get deleted. 
Why is this happening?

I'm pretty new to Android development so I'm just trying to learn Android, my apologies if this is a low quality question.

Hoping to see some answer regarding this happening. I did some research on Google & YouTube and StackExchange, I'm sure I did everything correctly, just the constraints themself started disappearing after some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could happen because constrain layout is still in beta. This will come with a lot of bug like these for instance. It could happen that it deleted all the constrains or maybe u accidentally pressed the 'clear all constrains' button in android studio.

You can check if constrains are still there by looking in to the text tab in edition to the design tab. And look for

```
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

or any other variaty.

Since the constraint layout is still in beta. I would recommend just using the other layouts of android (Linear, grid, relative etc.).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I've checked and there is no constraints in the XML meaning that it's probably due to some bug in the beta phase of ConstraintLayout. Guess I will check out other layouts.